# Jquery or Ajax dropdown div

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, xhtml

I pulled a (working) jquery dropdown from some website and I don't really understand why it's not working for my page, here's my code:

```
Head

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".hidden").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  jQuery(".row").click(function()
  {
    jQuery(this).next(".hidden").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
</script>


Body:
    <div id="likelyToBeWarned">
    <div id="likelyOddHeader" class="row">
        <div id="likelyOddA" class="left">Test</div>
        <div id="LikelyOddB" class="middle"><img class="middle" src="image002.png"/></div>
        <div id="timeZone" class="right">West</div>
        <div id ="rows" class="hidden">
            <div id="weights" class="left">Weights:</div>
            <div id="values" class="middle">ValueA:1234  ValueB:12345 ValueC:123456 ValueD:7654321</div>
            <div id="dbWeights" class="right">dbWeightA: 1234 dbWeightB:12345 dbWeightC:123456 dbWeightD:7654321</div>
        </div>



style/css

.hidden{
 position:relative;
 display: table-row;
 height:45px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}

.left{
    display: table-cell;
}

.right{
display: table-cell;
}

.middle{
display: table-cell;
cursor:pointer;
}
.row{
 display: table-row;
 height:45px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}
```

Edit:  The idea is to show the "hidden" div as a drop down of the "likelyOddHeader" div.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing div in your HTML code

```
<div id="likelyOddHeader" class="row">
    <div id="likelyOddA" class="left">Test</div>
    <div id="LikelyOddB" class="middle">blablah</div>
    <div id="timeZone" class="right">West</div>
</div> <---------------------------HERE 
<div id ="rows" class="hidden">
        <div id="weights" class="left">Weights:</div>
        <div id="values" class="middle">ValueA:1234  ValueB:12345 ValueC:123456 ValueD:7654321</div>
        <div id="dbWeights" class="right">dbWeightA: 1234 dbWeightB:12345 dbWeightC:123456 dbWeightD:7654321</div>
</div>​
```

I added that div in the fiddle and it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/CZjZs/1/

Answer (score 1):

This line `jQuery(this).next(".hidden")` returns empty set as `this` is `.row` element and `.hidden` is his child not a sibling.

Use

```
jQuery(this).children(".hidden")
```

or

```
jQuery(this).find(".hidden")
```

Or move `.hidden` element to be a sibling of `.row`

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery:

> jQuery(".row").click(function()   { 
>       jQuery(this).next(".hidden").slideToggle(500); 
>   });

.row is refering to a class. Your html shows a id..
so it should be :

```
$('#row').click(function(){
  $(this).slideToggle(500);
});
```

The #row (this) is on the same line as .hidden in the html. either you focus on the id (#row) or on the class (.hidden) and make the slideToggle on that.

```
jQuery(this).next(".hidden").slideToggle(500);
```

Comment: They are actually referring to the "class" row since the div with the id "rows" is the hidden one which you can't click on if it's hidden